# Why are JavaScript event names all lowercase?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, handler

I was having issues with 'transitionEnd' not firing, until I realized it had to be 'transitionend'. I know that in the documentation for the [TransitionEvent interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TransitionEvent) shows the events as all lowercase but my brain was typing in camelcase. Upon further looking I noticed all event names are lowercase, but nearly everything else in JavaScript is camelcase.

I took a look at the [specs for UIEvent](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type), but couldn't find anything mentioning the requirement for lowercase event names. It just says it's a DOMString and the only reference in that doc to lowercase was in relation to keycode events. Why are the UIEvent names required to be lowercase and where exactly is that specified?

Comment: Events come from the DOM.

Comment: Someone from further upstreams syntax preference. The age old arguement between camelCase, hyphen-case, nocase. but as @VLAZ said above writers of the DOM made it so.

You can write custom events with camelCase if you desire.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/ is the html spec. All the default events are there. If you create your own events, they may be cased however you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I asked and got this reply from Brendan Eich.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-origin-of-lower-casing-DOM-object-events-and-event-methods:

> I imitated HyperCard event names, e.g. click (Used with the `on`
> keyword: `on click ...` in HyperTalk):
>
> ftp://ftp.apple.asimov.net/pub/apple_II/documentation/misc/Apple%20HyperTalk%20Beginner%27s%20Guide.pdf
>
> JS followed Java, which followed Smalltalk, in using camelCaps for
> method names and StudlyCaps for "class names".

We see from the HyperTalk pdf on page 96 that those events were specified as:

```
on mouseUp
  play "boing"
end mouseUp
```

Which explains why the first word after "on" was lowercase. But the look of `onmouseUp` isn't so hot, my guess is that Brendan Eich liked the look of the all lowercase start, and extended lowercase to the whole event: `onmouseup`.

Comment: Marty Nelson, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @KiranShahi Edited to explain the historical context that answers OP question